# I need help debugging apache with gdb (no debugging symbols found)

Tags: apache-2.2, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to debug a segfault in PHP/Apache running on RHEL4.

This is a production server, so I'm trying to install a separate copy of Apache and PHP, and run apache through `gdb`.

When I load `httpd` through `gdb` and then do `run -X`, I get the error:

```
(no debugging symbols found)...
Error while reading shared library symbols:
Dwarf Error: Cannot handle DW_FORM_strp in DWARF reader.
```

The Apache manual says something about setting EXTRA_CFLAGS to `-g`, and I've tried configuring with `--enable-maintainer-mode`, but I don't seem to be getting far.

Comment: Related: [How to get current PHP function name in gdb?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/9558/12021)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be difficult to debug a complex multi-process/threaded network daemon application like Apache, complete with modules (such as potentially including mod_PHP) via gdb.

Why do you think the error lies **within** Apache's `httpd`, and not either an application (i.e. a PHP script) or module (e.g. `mod_PHP`)?

What is the exact segfault error message?

Does the segfault occur on startup, after a random while, after a certain web app is run, or a particular amount of time (*about every 48 hours*)?

Have you increase or added the Apache httpd [`Log Level`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive in the Apache configuration file to get more information?
Try `info` or `debug` for the most information.

I've been using Apache httpd for nearly 15 years, and I have never had to debug the Apache web server daemon itself, so I'm surprised you appear to need to debug it using gdb.

---

> (no debugging symbols found)

This means that the debugging symbols are not included in the binary executable. Typically the compiler didn't have debugging enabled (`-g` flag with gcc), and/or the install process `strip`ped the executable file, to make it occupy less memory while running.

> Error while reading shared library symbols:

This error is about the shared (dynamically linked) libraries debug symbols.

> Dwarf Error: Cannot handle DW_FORM_strp in DWARF reader.

I haven't seen this error before, it may be occurring because Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 is built differently. [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) is a debugging information format. The other common format found on Linux systems is [Stabs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabs). <s>Basically seems to be suggesting the shared libraries are also "stripped" of debugging information.</s>

*Correction:* It means that debugger (`gdb`) cannot read / find the string pointer (`strp`).  It may be due to GDB [Bug 7358](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7358) or a compiler / debugger version mismatch.

The shared libraries often have the debugging information (symbols) in a separate package. For example, I believe RHEL the GNU Standard C Library (glibc) debug info is in a package called `glibc-debug`. You will need to install the debug info of the libraries that Apache httpd uses. Check the Apache rpm package's libraries dependencies for a [list of libraries the executable depends upon](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-what-dependencies-a-rpm-file-has/) -- `rpm -qR package-name` or `rpm -qpR <rpm-file>`.

---

> i've tried configuring with --enable-maintainer-mode, but I don't seem to be getting far.

I'm sorry, but that's too vague to help you with. You need to include more useful details.

*Update:* Usage of `automake`'s [maintainer-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/maintainer_002dmode.html) is mostly for packaging or development, not debugging proposes.

---

Consider using a PHP debugger, like [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) with the PHP application or script.

---

**Summarize comments**

I'll try to summarize the information from the comments here:

- [Generating a gdb backtrace](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php) (from PHP)
- requires PHP built with debugging (symbols included)
- PHP with debugging can be built by making it using `EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g" make` or
- Preferably by using `configure --enable-debug` ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php#configure.options.misc)), followed by `make`

This appears to have resolved the debugging symbols.

Comment: This is the way the PHP documentation recommends debugging segfaults from a PHP script. http://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php
Basically I have a PHP script which is intermittently crashing, and apache is leaving this in its logs: [notice] child pid 20242 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/httpd

Comment: As far the -g flag for gcc, I've tried to add that either as an environment variable (export EXTRA_CFLAGS), or by adding that to the make command (make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g"), and I still can't get it to work. Obviously, I don't *really* know what I'm doing.

Comment: maybe take a closerlook at the php code, and php apache module first.

Comment: From the PHP generating backtrace information, second paragraph titled _Important!_ : To get a backtrace with correct information you must have PHP configured with --enable-debug! So you want to build PHP, not Apache with debug information.

Comment: `make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g"` The EXTRA_CFLAGS is an environment variable, not a command parameter, you want to do `EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g" make`

Comment: Yes, you are correct...I do need to compile PHP with --enable-debug. I did just that, _and_ I recompiled apache as well. After that, I followed the instructions, and got that message from GDB. 
I figured `EXTRA_CFLAGS` was an environment variable, which is why I tried the `export` command shown in my comment. I also tried `make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g"` as well, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Tried `EXTRA_CFLAGS="-g" make` and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The 'strp' in `DW_FORM_strp` does not mean stripped; it means that the symbol attribute comes in the form of a pointer to a string (pointer to elsewhere within the symbol data.)  I would -1 except that I have insufficient reputation.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell I'm glad you didn't have the reputation to downvote, because as others have indicated the answer is not incorrect,  lacking of merit. Finally, as I have shown, I am also willing to fix mistakes. Thank you for the correction, it's much more productive.

Comment: @mctylr, my downvote would have been temporary, pending your edit.  Sorry for not being clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the debug symbols aren't getting stripped as part of the apache installation process. It's common to run 'strip' on binaries to remove said symbols when they get copied to /usr/local/bin or wherever.

Answer (score 0):

RH packs debug symbols in separate rpm packages.

Try installing these...

Comment: What are these packages called?

Comment: Actually that won't help me, since I'm compiling from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think the RPMs that contain debugging information are named `<pkg>-debuginfo-<...>`. You can install them with the `debuginfo-install <pkg>` command under Fedora 12, which may work under Red Hat systems too.